# insconsistent_build_configuration error when using debug

Tags: image, dlib

I am using Dlib for my project,
When I include these headers

```html
#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing/render_face_detections.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing.h>
```

These bugs appear. Are there any way to fix this. I have spend almost the whole day for thes bugs

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol USER_ERROR__inconsistent_build_configuration__see_dlib_faq_1 SmileLibrary    D:\Codelovers\riz-smil\SmileLibrary\Smile.obj   1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol USER_ERROR__inconsistent_build_configuration__see_dlib_faq_2 SmileLibrary    D:\Codelovers\riz-smil\SmileLibrary\Smile.obj   1